# Regex matching a quoted string or space

Tags: javascript, regex

Given the following string I would like to produce an array with each of the key / values.

this my test string:

```
key1:value1 key2: value2 key3:"value3" key4: "value4" key5:'value5' key6: 'value6'
```

Expected result:

```
params[key1] == 'value1'
params[key2] == 'value2'
params[key3] == 'value3'
params[key4] == 'value4'
params[key5] == 'value5'
params[key6] == 'value6'
```

This is what I have so far but it doesn't work with the " or ' quotes strings or spaces after the colon.

```
var re = /([^ ]*):([^ ]*)/g

while (match = re.exec(subject)) {
  params[match[1]] = match[2];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close.

```
 /([^ ]+):\s*(['"]?[^ '"]+['"]?)/g
```

That should do it. Note that this won't provide validation, so `key1: value1"` or `key1: 'value1"` will still pass. Validation would call for a more complicated pattern.

Comment: That did exactly what I needed.  Thank you!  My eyes start to cross when I look at these RegEx's for too long.

Comment: I actually omitted a requirement.  The reason for the " ' is because the value could contain a space.  So key7: "My Key".  Using yours matches 'key7' and  '"My' (not '"My Key"') .  What would I need to change to match the fully quoted string?

Comment: @ChrisDev - I think `/([^ ]+):\s*([^ ]+|'[^']+'|"[^"]+")/g` should do it. That will also provide decent (though maybe not perfect) validation.

Comment: That seems to still only grab the "My but not "My Key".  I'll keep playing with it to see if I can get it work.  I appreciate you getting me this far.

Comment: I made a change to the order and got it working  `/([^ ]+):\s*('[^']+'|"[^"]+"|[^ ]+)/g` Thanks again!

Comment: Oh, I see why that happened. I should have had `([^ '"]+|...` if I wrote them in that order. Glad you got it working.